# Interface não atualiza no Emulador

Tags: android-studio

Estou criando uma tela no Android Studio, criei o emulador está rodando tudo certo.

Aí adicionei alguns componente nessa tela.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Só que quando vou olhar o aplicativo no emulador ele não atualiza a tela com os novos componentes que adicionei.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Passei pelo mesmo problema há pouco tempo mano, imagino que você tenha atualizado o android studio há pouco tempo. Você terá de usar um novo emulador, é só criar um novo.

Comment: Então no caso  eu posso deletar esse emulador, e criar ele mesmo de novo que roda ? @BonecoSinforoso

Comment: Creio que sim, um com as mesmas configurações, agora ele vai ser totalmente novo e não vai ter seus outros apk's e talz, só você adicioná-los normalmente.

Comment: tentar aqui então.

Comment: cirei um novo emulador, e agora não está aparecendo o aplicativo @BonecoSinforoso

Comment: abra-o através do android studio

Comment: Não deu certo, o app não aparece no emulador, estou criando um novo projeto pra vê se da certo @BonecoSinforoso

Comment: dá algum erro no log?

Comment: Conseguir resolver aqui, era aquilo que você disse mesmo, Obrigado @BonecoSinforoso